# Rsync - Recursively Include Few of Many Folders in One Statement

Tags: rsync

For the sake of this post, lets assume I have a folder called "misc" that has 100 sub-folder named 001 to 100. Each folder has many sub-folders and files.

I want to write one rsync command that recursively backs up only the folders named 009, 053, and 087.

This command works fine for backing up the entire "misc" folder:

```
rsync -v --progress --recursive /home/user/misc /home/user/backup/misc
```

I've made several attempts to use include and exclude parameters (to only backup the particular sub-folders I want), but each attempt has resulted in /home/user/backup/misc being an empty folder after the command is run successfully.

Could someone add to this command (above) the proper use of include and exclude parameters to achieve what I'm attempting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`rsync -avz` will backup all files, recursively. If you script your rsync into a bash script, you can just back those particular folders

Exampe:

```
#!/bin/bash
rsync -avz /home/user/misc/009 /home/user/backup/misc/
rsync -avz /home/user/misc/053 /home/user/backup/misc/
rsync -avz /home/user/misc/087 /home/user/backup/misc/
```

Comment: This is very nice approach and I may use it ultimately. However, I'm still very interested in how to achieve this using one rsync command with include/exclude statements.

Comment: Include/Exclude are meant more for filenames.  Example: `rsync -avz /home/user/misc /home/user/backup/ --exclude "exe"` would backup everything in `/home/user/misc` except files with "exe" in it. I guess, technically, you could do `--include "folder/" --exclude "*"` and it should exclude everything, then include the folder (but I'm fairly certain you can only explicity include 1 thing and explicitly exclude 1 thing, which means you'll need a script anyway). If you need more info about it, you can read the man page: http://ss64.com/bash/rsync.html